# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'wchar.h' file not found in Xcode after software updating to Big Sur 11.1 and Xcode 12.3

Tags: c++, xcode12, macos-big-sur, software-update

I just updated to macOS Big Sur 11.1 today. I am using a MacBook Pro with the M1 chip. The OS software update itself said the there were updates for Xcode included in the update. I have done research for this problem and many people noted that the problem may be due to the absence of a "include" folder in "/usr". Indeed there was no  "include" folder there when I checked. I just switched to Mac from Windows. Could it be caused by a different issue? How do I fix this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I installed and reinstalled Xcode command line tools and that did the trick.